# Uniformly distribute Points within an object using Graphics in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, point

Considering :

```
preferred ={{1, 1, 63}, {2, 1, 44}, {3, 1, 27}, {4, 1, 33}, {5, 1, 33}}

frmWidth  =                 20.9067;
frmHeight =                   15.68;
```

I am displaying 5 types of stimuli 2 by 2. Subjects must choose the one they prefer. Each type of stimuli is displayed 80 times so :

{1,1,63} indicates that the stimuli Cond 1 was preferred 63 times out of the 80 times it was displayed.
{3, 1, 27} indicates that the stimuli Cond 3 was preferred 27 times out of the 80 times it was displayed.

Cond1 refers to center of the screen

Cond2 refers to Top-Left Quadrant

Cond3 refers to Top-Right Quadrant

Cond4 refers to Bottom-Left Quadrant

Cond5 refers to Bottom-Right Quadrant

I would like to express this showing results.

This is what I have done :

```
Graphics[{
  Black, EdgeForm[{Thin, LightGray}], 
  Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {frmWidth + 1, frmHeight + 1}], 

  PointSize[0.03],
  Yellow,
  Point@Tuples[{Range[0, frmWidth/2, frmWidth/19], 
  Range[0, frmHeight/2, frmHeight/14]}][[;; preferred[[5, 3]]]],

  Red,
  Point@Tuples[{Range[frmWidth/2, frmWidth, frmWidth/19], 
  Range[0, frmHeight/2, frmHeight/14]}][[;; preferred[[4, 3]]]],

  Green,
  Point@Tuples[{Range[frmWidth/2, frmWidth, frmWidth/19], 
  Range[frmHeight/2, frmHeight, frmHeight/14]}][[;; preferred[[3, 3]]]],

  Orange,
  Point@Tuples[{Range[0, frmWidth/2, frmWidth/19], 
  Range[frmHeight/2, frmHeight, frmHeight/14]}][[;; 
  preferred[[2, 3]]]],

  Blue,
  Point@Tuples[{Range[frmWidth/4, 3/4 frmWidth, frmWidth/19], 
  Range[frmHeight/4, 3/4 frmHeight, frmHeight/14]}][[;; 
  preferred[[1, 3]]]]

  }]
```

[image]

**Problem is the rectangles are gradually filled with points from left to right, instead of the points being uniformly located.**

Consider the following :

```
Graphics[{

  White, EdgeForm[Thick], 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {frmWidth, frmHeight}],

  Orange, Opacity[.5],
  Rectangle[{0, frmHeight/2}, {frmWidth/2, frmHeight}, RoundingRadius -> 3],

  Green,
  Rectangle[{frmWidth/2, frmHeight/2}, {frmWidth, frmHeight},RoundingRadius -> 3],

  Red,
  Rectangle[{frmWidth/2, 0}, {frmWidth, frmHeight/2}, RoundingRadius -> 3],

  Yellow,
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {frmWidth/2, frmHeight/2}, RoundingRadius -> 3],

  Blue,
  Rectangle[{frmWidth/4, frmHeight/4}, {3/4 frmWidth, 3/4 frmHeight}, RoundingRadius -> 3]
  }]
```

[image]

Now I would like to fill those edge rounded rectangles with the points but have the density changing rather than the part of the rectangles that are filled.

Below is something very ugly I draw in PPT :

[image]

**Ideally, the shapes filled with Points could be of any kind.
Points would not overlap.**

Please let me know alternative ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, try this:

```
Manipulate[ld = Floor[Sqrt[n]];
Graphics[
{{EdgeForm[Dashed], White, 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, h}, {w, h}, {w, 0}}]},
 Point[Flatten[#, 1] &@
 Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, w, w/ld}, {y, 0, h, h/ld}]] },
PlotRange \[Rule] {{-1, 20}, {-1, 20}}],
{{n, 25}, 10, 100, 1},
{{h, 10}, 5, 20},
{{w, 10}, 5, 20}]
```

typical configuration:

[image]

(the code I gave lets you control the total number and size of the box via sliders)

Comment: @acl, could the density be automatically adjusted given the size of the box and the number of dots to be present ?

Comment: @500 so, something like this?

Comment: @acl, yes it seems, ingredients are in there !

Comment: @500 what's missing? should be easy enough to add (I haven't yet thought of how to do it efficiently for non-rectangular containers)

Comment: @acl, that`s it, if this could work for arbitrary shapes :) Principle is exctly what I was looking for

Comment: @500 in what form are the shapes to be defined?

Comment: @acl, Within Graphics, for now, rounded corner rectangle, but I hope to then use polygon based on ConvexHull.

Comment: @500 well it is easy enough if I have y1[x] and y2[x] which define the upper and lower curves of the shape. with polygons, i guess it is also doable (well it clearly is, the question is, with how much effort-10min, 1h, 1day? I have no idea)

Comment: @acl, let me first implement it as such ;) We`ll see how that goes !

Comment: @acl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/972/discussion-between-500-and-acl)

Answer (score 0):

Given that your rectangles are rather small, the easiest solution is to use

```
RandomSample[ allPointsInAnObject ]
```

Kind of like so:

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 11], PointSize[0.02], 
  Point[RandomSample[
    Cases[Outer[List, Range[-11, 11], Range[-11, 11]], {x_, y_} /; 
      x^2 + y^2 <= 11^2, {2}], 50]]}]
```

Comment: but I thought he wanted a uniform density throughout the object, changing to accomodate a given total number?